# success: function(data); not working with named function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently use a annonymous function for the jquery ajax success-response.

```
success: function(data){
  code
},
```

When Trying to use a named function:

```
success: success(data),
```

It claims the the variable data is not set. I suppose i could do

```
success: function(data){
  success(data)
},
```

But this feels like it's not how it's suppose to be done. Why is it behaving this way and what should I do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because JQuery is expecting a *reference* to a function, not a *function call*.

JQuery needs to know what function has to call. With `success(data)` you are instead passing the *result* of the function call `success(data)` (which can be whatever, also void - no result) giving no clue at all for what to do.

The reference is something that points to an object, in this case a "function object".
The function call can be thought instead as an *action* to perform that gives or gives not a result that is evaluated as an expression.

Just use:

```
success: success
```

Comment: I see. Is it possible to pass any extra variables with the function?

Answer (score 1):

You need to only pass the *reference*. You do that, buy just passing in the *name*, like

```
success: success
```

---

What you did so far, is to execute the function `success` by typing the parenthesis and assign the return value from that function.

Comment: I see. Is it possible to pass any extra variables with the function?

Answer (score 1):

the `success` property takes an object of type `function`. `function(data) { }` returns a function. `success(data)` *calls* the function and returns whatever it returns. If your function is called `success`, you just do:

```
success: success,
```

Comment: I see. Is it possible to pass any extra variables with the function?